# Generate PDF using XSL-FO from DB not XML source

Tags: .net, pdf, xsl-fo

I have only XSL-FO document without its source XML file given by client, and I should generate PDF by assigning values into this XSL-fo file  from my DB.

My questions are,
1.Is it considered normal development to use only XSL-FO without its source XML file, or should I ask the XML schema of the source XML that they used to transform and make this XSL-FO?

In following article it the author says:
"The typical generation of XSLFO would be from our XML using an XSLT stylesheet, though this need not be the case at all. We may have situations where our applications need to express information in a paginated form, and these applications could generate instances of the XSLFO vocabulary directly to be interpreted for the output medium."
Source: http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/939

2.How can I effectively assign values to attributes starting with @ signs, such as @agencyType and etc.

3 Which library do you suggest to generate PDF in .NET usinf XSL-Fo?

Here is the example from that XSL files I have:

```
xsl:when test="@paymentType=5 or @paymentType=8"/>
        <xsl:when test="parent::node()/@isCopy='true' "/>
            <xsl:when test="@agencyType='3' "/>
            <xsl:when test="@separateAgencyCommissionInvoiceNumber!='' "/>
            <xsl:when test="@differentShipmentAddress='true' ">
                <fo:page-sequence master-reference="Rechnung">
                    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before" font-family="Verdana" font-size="8.5pt" line-height="10pt">
                        <fo:block-container width="17cm" height="2cm" top="-3mm" left="0cm" position="absolute">
                            <fo:block font-family="CourierNew" font-size="1pt" line-height="6pt">
                                <xsl:variable name="headerLine1">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="translate(../InserterHeaderLine/@headerLine1,'A1U','A1 ')"/>
                                </xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:value-of select="translate($headerLine1,' ','~')"/>
                            </fo:block>
                            <fo:block font-family="CourierNew" font-size="1pt" line-height="6pt">
                                <xsl:value-of select="translate(../InserterHeaderLine/@headerLine2,' ','~')"/>
                            </fo:block>
                            <fo:block font-family="CourierNew" font-size="1pt" line-height="6pt">
                                <xsl:value-of select="translate(../InserterHeaderLine/@headerLine3,' ','~')"/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </fo:static-content>
                    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" font-size="9pt" font-family="Verdana">
                        <!--    abweichende Rechnungsanschrift -->
                        <fo:block-container width="9cm" height="4cm" top="2.4cm" left="0cm" position="absolute">
                            <fo:block>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@shipmentName1Line"/>
                            </fo:block>
                            <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@shipmentName2Line"/>
                        </fo:block>
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@shipmentName3Line"/>
                        </fo:block>
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@shipmentAddress1Line"/>
                        </fo:block>
                        <fo:block>&#160;</fo:block>
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@shipmentAddress2Line"/>
                        </fo:block>
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@shipmentAddress3Line"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:block-container>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I do not really understand the question. How does one have "XSL-FO document without its source XML file given by client, and I should generate PDF by assigning values into this XSL-fo file from my DB.?" Does this mean you have an XSL FO file with the content already in it? Or do you have an XSL file with things like xsl:value-of?

Answer (score 0):

Given the examples you have shown above, you have an "XSL" file (not an "XSL FO" file). You can (a) examine that XSL and determine an XML file the fits it or (b) I would be surprised the person who gave you the XSL does not have a sample XML file, get it from them.

Then generate an XML from your DB matching it. This can be done with many tools, RenderX has a free one called DB2XML or you can look at those from Altova or other vendors.